# Repeating same processes for multiple csv files

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am a beginner of Python. I have about 1000 CSV files (1.csv, 2.csv....1000.csv). Each CSV file has about 3,000,000,000 rows and 14 variables. I would like to clean data in each CSV file first using the same process for each CSV file:

1. sum variable A and variable B,
2. count C by sorting date, if the number of records in C for one day is greater than 50, then drop it.

Next, save the cleaned data into a new CSV file. At last, append all 1000 new CSV files into one CSV file.

I have some code as follows, but it imports all CSV files first, then process to clean data, which is very inefficient. I would like to clean the data in each CSV file first, then append new CSV files. Can anyone help me on this? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Youll need to show us what you've tried, and perhaps sample input/out aligned with [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1,000 files, each with 3 billion rows? This sounds like a job for a database, not Python. You could use Python to read the CSV files and import them into a DB, then do the processing via the DB. Also, what do you mean by "variables"? CSV files don't contain variables. Do you mean columns?

Comment: This looks like a pandas question, rather than a mere python question. I say this only because you are using `pandas.read_csv()` with two rows of header data. Otherwise, you could do your cleanup and create new set of CSVs using python's built-in csv module. Of course, you could still do this, but you would need to explicitly set fieldnames in [csv.DictReader()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html), and then ignore the first two header rows. If that's an approach you're willing to take, post the first few rows of one of your files and I or someone else could help.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I understand from your question.  I read all the files and I add a new column for the summation. Then I order the date and drop any value of C greater than 50. After that, I save the update. Before you do this you have to copy your original files or you can save them with a different files name.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "./data/"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) #make list of paths

for file in all_files:
    # Getting the file name without extension
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    df['new_column'] =  df['A']+ df['B']
    df.sort_values(by='C')
    df.drop(df.loc[df['C']>50].index, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(file_name)
```